# ComboBox FXML default value

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-2, fxml

How can I set a default value in a `ComboBox` using FXML?

```
<ComboBox fx:id="cbo_Bacteriologie_Aesculine" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="105.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="NVT" />
            <String fx:value="Bezig" />
            <String fx:value="Positief" />
            <String fx:value="Negatief" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

I want `NVT` to be selected by default. I tried adding `selected="selected"` and such but don't seem to find the right syntax.

Is it possible to edit the listed items using Scene Builder? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="NVT" />
            <String fx:value="Bezig" />
            <String fx:value="Positief" />
            <String fx:value="Negatief" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
    <value>
        <String fx:value="NVT" />
    </value>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: `<ComboBox value="NVT">` works too and looks cleaner.

Comment: Gives `javafx.fxml.LoadException: String is not a valid type.`

Comment: @BappadityaSasmal you need to import String class. `<?import java.lang.String?>`

Comment: dont forget these imports : 
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.collections.ObservableList?>

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's possible in the FXML. You will need to do it in the initialization of the component, in the controller, for example using the following line `cbo_Bacteriologie_Aesculine.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);` for selecting the element Bezig.

But if you find a way to do it in FXML, I am interested.

EDIT : It is possible in FXML. You can see it in Guedolino's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436371/1344424), which should become the right answer to this question.

Comment: okay I used the following code `cbo_Bacteriologie_Aesculine.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();` and it does the trick. I hope there will come support to handle this in FXML :)

Answer (score 6):

I got a strange error with the first suggested method

> setSelectedItem(T) has protected access in SelectionModel
>     where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in class SelectionModel

For me

```
getSelectionModel().select("NVT");
```

worked like a charm.